# Fix the height of table in html while printing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created a report which is displayed in a webpage.
It's a set of tables one below the other. It has total 4 tables. Now, out of 4, 3 tables are having fixed height( content are fixed), but one table has content in which number of rows vary. How can i keep the height of this table fixed, irrespective of the content. If the height increases, then the content size(row size) should be minimized, as the whole report should be printed on a single A4 size paper.
 I have tried using **min-height** and **max-height**.

Comment: So if the number of rows increase, the height of the rows should decrease to fit it all onto one page? Or should the overflow just be hidden/scrollable?

Comment: Yes.  The rows height should decrease to fit all in one page.  No scrolling because it is to be printed in one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't going to be a "one size fits all" solution for this. There will be a maximum number of rows that can be displayed to fit everything on one physical A4 page. Imagine this maximum is 10 rows, as soon as you hit 11 rows it will spill over to the next page.

You can reduce the table cell height from the off to increase the number of rows that can be displayed but you can only make the cells so small before they become unreadable.

Once you know the best maximum you may wish to build a "maximum report size" into your application which prevents more than this maximum numbers of rows being output to the page in the first place.

You may be able to consider reducing the width of this table to less than 50% of the page width, then have two tables side-by-side. This depends on how many columns you need to display of course. You may also be able to fit some of the other 3 tables side-by-side using this method.

EDIT:

As I said in the comments the way to find the row height would be to divide the total available height by the number of rows. So if you have 400 pixels available and need to display 8 rows then:

```
400 / 8 = 50
```

Each row must be 50 pixels in height - this will be including padding and borders so take this into account. Setting this in your C# will likely be the fastest way to apply this to all rows.

Comment: Thanks for your insights.  I would like to know, after i find my max number of rows that can be fitted in a page, how can i alter my cell heights depending on the number of rows? Reducing the width is not possible as we have to follow a strict format as provided by the client.

Comment: You'll see to use some logic to find this, I would recommend doing this in your .NET code. Once you know how many rows you can have, find the total height of all of the rows - this is the total height that you can use. Then it's simple formula:

row_height = total_height / number_of_rows

So if you have a total height of 400 pixels and are displaying 8 rows:

400 / 8 = 50 pixels of height per row.

Of course you'll also have to take into account borders and padding of your cells but these are basic CSS changes.